# Trying to monitor file/folder changes on the server and send notification. What am I dong wrong?

Tags: ubuntu, email, amazon-ec2, scripting

I am trying to make a script to monitor a directory of the EC2 webserver I am managing. I found inotify and tried to make the following script but upon trying it nothing happened.

```
#!/bin/sh

while inotifywait --monitor --recursive --event create --event delete /var/www/usrfiles; do

    echo "Files on the server have changed." | mail -s "server change" email@emailaddress.com

done
```

http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait

Comment: Just as a reference making the following changes made this runnable but like EEAA said better ways are to be found.

    while :; inotifywait (no --monitor) [options]; do; -- email; -- done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want incron. It takes care of this sort of thing in a much easier, more reliable fashion than trying to hack things together yourself.

http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=about&lang=en

Comment: I am marking this answered because I used this for a while with success before altering the entire implementation. This, incron, works very well.